# CSS: Child Element Not Containing Inside Parent Element

Tags: css, positioning

So I have a container at the bottom of my site that holds two columns, like so:

```
<div id="homeBottomContent">
<div id="homeColumn1" class="contentColumn column1">
<h2>Column 1</h2>
<p>Column 1 Stuff</p>
</div>
<div id="homeColumn2" class="contentColumn column2">
<h2>Column 2</h2>
<p>Column 2 Stuff
</p></div>
</div>
```

When I tried to give the columns an 80% width and 10% margins, like so:

```
.column1, .column2 {
width: 80%;
margin: 1em 10%;
}

.column1 {
float:left;
}

.column2 {
clear: left;
}
```

My columns aren't centered within the box. They skew off to the right a little bit. So, when I took the margins away and tried:

```
.column1, .column2 {
width: 100%;
}
```

They stretch outside the #homeBottomContent div and off the page. What could be causing this, and what can I do to fix it? I have no side padding or margins on the #homeBottomContent div.

Comment: Any padding on `.column1` or `.column2`?

Comment: Update here: for some reason, when I clear both columns to the left, give them margin: 1em auto and set the width below 100%, it works like a charm. I'm still curious as to why the float didn't work though.

Comment: @BrianRay yep, good call. 1em of padding all around, that would be why 100% took it out of the container. Thanks

Comment: The clear property specifies which side(s) of an element other floating elements are not allowed.